# Filtering in HTML through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am trying to add a  "filter" feature to the bios section, where each bio is listed in a list (ul and li). I've to filter them by region, sector and functional expertise; which is ofcourse part of the attribute of each list.

My question is how can I achieve it through an efficient cross-browser.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your requirements match quite well with what the javascript plugin called list.js
was made for.

1. http://listjs.com/
2. http://listjs.com/examples
3. https://github.com/javve/list

Comment: Thanks. Would this work (Isotope), http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html?

Comment: @Steve - what *have* you tried? Do you need to filter just by category? isotope should work, but you should be aware of its license; list.js would also work. If you need to filter by category AND by data input, list.js looks preferable. But it's not clear to me what your requirements are, in so far as isotope is much more about "filtering" with "cool" animations.